# undefined symbol: expert_register_field_array Wireshark generic.so

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, wireshark

I want to use the Mqtt Dissector provided [here](http://false.ekta.is/2011/06/mqtt-dissector-decoder-for-wireshark/) And for that i download the generic.so from http://wsgd.free.fr/ and put it in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wireshark/libwireshark3/plugins` folder but when i run wireshark i get following error:

Couldn't load module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wireshark/libwireshark3/plugins/generic.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wireshark/libwireshark3/plugins/generic.so: undefined symbol: expert_register_field_array

i am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and wireshark Version 1.10.6

Comment: *Which* generic.so did you download?  There is more than one on [the download page](http://wsgd.free.fr/download.html); did you download the one for Wireshark 1.6.X, the one for Wireshark 1.8.X, the one for Wireshark 1.10.X, or the one for Wireshark 1.12.X?

Comment: @GuyHarris the 1.10.x one. The problem resolved after i restarted my pc.